# Qt Slots and Signals. Get Slot Receiver Object

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.5

I have a QLineEdit which I Want to connect to a QLabel so that depending on the validity of the text entered. I have two problems while doing this.

```
QLineEdit *text = new QLineEdit(this);
layout->addWidget(text, rowno, 0);
QLabel *button = new QLabel(this);
button->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : green; color : white; }");
button->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
button->setText("OKAY");
QObject::connect(text, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &)), button, SLOT(CheckValidity(const QString &)));
```

this does not connect any changes made in QLineEdit to my custom slot. I cannot figure out why!
Also in the custom slot, I want to change the background colour of my label depending on the QString passed. How do I get a reference for the label? It is present as the receiver of the signal but I can't figure out a way to refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckValidity` is not a `QButton`'s slot, it's a custom slot defined in your own class (I assume that, since you have not specified it).

So, change the last line to:

```
QObject::connect(text, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &)), this, SLOT(CheckValidity(const QString &)));
```

If you want to know the sender object, use `qobject_cast`:

```
QLabel *sender_label = qobject_cast<QLabel*> (sender ());
```

Comment: Can I pass the label as an argument in the custom slot? I believe QT signals and slots need to have the same number of arguments, but i need to connect a particular label with a particular textbox and they are created dynamically by the user at runtime, hence I cannot keep a reference to it in my class.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no `CheckValidity` slot in `QLabel` (why `button` is `QLabel`?). Check output window of debugger after connection trying.
2. `QObject::sender()` + cast. Cast may be `dynamic_cast` or `qobject_cast`, look their difference in Qt Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to supply additional arguments into your slot invocation, you can use lambda instead of a slot:

```
QObject::connect(text, &QLineEdit::textEdited, [=](const QString &text) { checkValidity(button, text); });
```